# Direct command lego ev3

Tags: ev3, bluetooth

Is there any documentation about direct command bluetooth of EV3?

Thanks,
regards!

Comment: What do mean by direct command? Do you want to, using code running on the EV3, communicate directly to the EV3 bluetooth module?

Comment: There are bluetooth commands to drive the motors directly, without the help of ev3 use a program, but there is no documentation about them. I get some commands from source codes of any libraries, I can control motors ev3 by set velocity and power, but I can't control this by step or degrees

Answer (score 0):

Try http://ev3.fantastic.computer/doxygen/index.html and http://ev3.fantastic.computer/doxygen-all/

It seems to be the best option at the moment.